# Please help a new giyoret kasher her kitchen

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

Okay so I've done quite a bit of reading on how to kasher, on what items can and can't be kashered, and how to maintain a kosher kitchen. I have an appointment with my rabbi to come over and help with the actual kashering part of it.

My question, however, is with the preparation. I know you need to clean everything really well first and then let it sit for 24 hours, but I'm having a ton of trouble figuring out the basic logistics of the cleaning process because everything I've found assumes I already know this piece of it.

Mostly what I'm trying to figure out is:

1. What are the rules for things touching each other after the cleaning? Can I, for instance, empty the cupboards, clean the cupboards, clean the items I emptied out, and then put them back in?
2. Is it fine if I put down fresh shelf paper?
3. If not, what am I supposed to do with the displaced (but clean) items in the meantime? I have cats and they are likely to try and play with items that are just sitting out.
4. Can I use an un-koshered dishwasher to do the washing, or do I need to do the washing all by hand?
5. When does the 24-hour wait time begin? Once I'm done with all of it? Or do I need to remember the exact order I did things in?
6. During the 24-hour wait period, what should I do for food? Eat out? Use disposable dishes? Can I bring food into the kitchen?
7. Also, during the actual kashering process, where do I put all of the newly kashered dishes until the surfaces they need to sit on are also kashered? Or, should I do the surfaces first and then the items?

I really don't want to waste my rabbi's time and want to get this right! Thanks in advance!!

(Possibly important note: my kitchen is very small and I'm aiming for dairy-only.)

Comment: Don't worry too much about wasting your rabbi's time with practical questions. That's what he's there for (among other things, of course).

Comment: @Rachel Hi Rachel, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. It is an honor to speak with a new Giyoret as well. This site is not made for asking about a specific case of practical Jewish Law that should rather be posed to your Rabbi; but the question makes sense and is a fine one. If you cannot reach your Rabbi right now and need to learn some Torah about kashrus that would help you to demystify the situation, you can feel free to e-mail me at davidariel25@gmail.com I can help you understand some things and help you form the right question if you need to ask your Rabbi.

Comment: Some of the above questions — any that don't pertain to only your specific circumstances — are general-information questions or can be reformulated as such. For example, "Can one use a non-kosher dishwasher to clean non-kosher dishes in preparation for kashering those dishes?". And feel free to ask that separately (this post had too many disparate questions in it anyway), but be sure to take what you read on this site as informative only and to ask your rabbi for a practical ruling.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Rachel and thanks for this first question. Don't let yourself being discouraged, there is much information here you will find helpful. It is just that this first question is too broad to be answered as is - breaking it down in parts will make it easier to get answers (or see if already covered elsewhere). Hope to see you around!